# Disable escaping in Android Volley

Tags: java, android, escaping, android-volley

In my Android application I use [escapeJson](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJson(java.lang.String)) on the strings (which are created by the user) I upload to my server using [StringRequest](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html). If the strings contain a new line then the string on the server contains `\\n` instead of `\n` at each new line.

```
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, myUrl,
        new Response.Listener(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Object response) {
                ...
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        ...
    }
}
){
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
    {
        Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("text", StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(text));
        return params;
    }
};
```

If I type some lines of text in my textview and send it to the server using code above each new line is represented by `\\n` when it should be `\n`. It seems like StringRequest is escaping each `\n`, can I disable that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is in escapeJson; I suggest that instead of allowing it to escape your string, use URLEncode in its place and URLDecode on the server.

**Edit**

Pre-converting the carriage return to Unicode before using escapeJson is also an option.

```
String modifiedText = originalText.replaceAll("\\n", "\\u000D");
```

Comment: I use `escapeJson` because I need to encode the emojis inputed by the user. If I use URLEncode I get `????` for every emoji instead of for example `\\uD83D\\uDE81`

Comment: You do realize that the '\\' may also cause you problems since its not valid in javascript; which is how I am assuming you end up displaying the text? If you're going android->server->android, just base64 encode the bytes and be done.

Comment: No I'm going android -> server -> iOS and the other way around. There is no problem until I write multiple rows on an Android device.

Comment: Ok, you could also preconvert the \\n or \n to its Unicode equivalent before escapeJson

Comment: Hmm, then the new lines just becomes `u000D` on the server instead of `\\u000D`

Comment: How does iOS expect and send it? "\u000D"? I'm fairly sure iOS won't agree with the '\\' escapes.

Comment: On iOS I use AFNetworking to do the request and I do no encoding myself, new rows are sent as `\n`

Comment: I tried setting `\u000D` directly in MySQL I get `u000D`, if I set `\\u000D` I get `\\u000D`. Maybe I'm missing something server-side